# How is Alliance Funding distributed?

Tags: mass-effect-3

What missions give Alliance funding?  I get it for a good amount of the priority missions as well as some of the side missions. I don't like doing hundreds of side missions unless they are rewarding for the time I spend on them.

Is there a way to know which missions give funding or even good rewards for that matter. I get useless war assets more then anything which I don't need now that my bar is maxed.

I apologize if this is a duplicate can't check on my phone very easily.

Comment: As a side note, having the bar maxed means nothing. You want to have over 4000 effective strength by the end if you want the best ending.

Comment: @mr smooth didnt know that, good to know

Comment: You get reputation for most of the side missions as well, which can help enable dialogue choices. Credits aren't the only rewards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure it's awarded after every 'real' mission.

(As in, every mission in which you have to go and shoot things, not Citadel fetch quests to scan planets).

The amount is fixed per-mission, and gradually rises as you progress through the game.

That said, the Citadel fetch-missions are among some of the most rewarding in the game, as they award incredible XP and credits on a per/time basis.